# Hibernate - Saving Entity Having @ManyToOne relationships with other entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

[Saving This entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVZQd.png)

I am Saving This Entity By Passing

```
{
    "amount":"5454",
    "billNo":"32456",
    "paidTo":"Yash",
    "expenseCategory":
    {
        "category":"tickets"
    },
    "modeOfPayment":
    {
        "paymentMethod":"phonepe"
    },
    "user":
    {
        "name":"Shivam Chaudhary",
        "password":"123456@"
    }
}
```

this json but every time the 'expenseCategory' , 'modeOfPayment' and 'User' also get saved duplicating many rows in respective entities.

I want that hibernate will check if these 'expenseCategory' and 'modeOfPayment' entries exists already and assign corresponding ids to the foreign_key column of expense otherwise create a new entry in 'expenseCategory', 'modeOfPayment'.

I am new to spring JPA any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As per your current scenarios, this will always create a new record resulting in duplicate records. You need to manually check if the record already exists if yes then based on the primary key it will update your record once you set that key to the new record

Comment: @shivamchaudhary Look at this [article](https://xebia.com/blog/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/). There are several traps when you try to save objects directly passed from request.

Comment: @shivamchaudhary And next time please add your code as a text, not as an image.